# Segue into TabBarController's specific ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Ok so I have a TabBarController that is segued up to four ViewControllers. One of these view controllers is set up so that when you select an item from a TableView It goes to a different ViewController that is not on the TabBarController. My problem arises when I want to go back from the ViewController that is not segued to the TabBarController. If I set up a push segue back to the  ViewController, I want to go to, it will transition but the TabBar does not appear. If I set up a segue going back to the TabBarController it shows the TabBar but it goes back to the first tab (which is definitely not what I want). Is there a way to tell it to go to the third tab or a specific ViewController? Or just create a segue directly back to the ViewController I want and have the tab bar appear.

This is what my storyboard looks like for a better reference. The VCs I am talking about are the ones in the middle right hand side.

[image]

Comment: Can't see your storyboard. A UITabBarController has a property called viewControllers which is an array of the root view controllers displayed.

Comment: So when I make a segue from the ViewController to the TabBarController I can tell it what ViewController I want with this array? I put up a link the the storyBoard (don't have enough points to post images).

Comment: That picture is a too small to make out much. Do you have like a "Back" button or something on that VC that is not on the Tab Bar Controller? If you do, you might be able to set it up from the storyboard.

Comment: If you click on the image a bigger version pops up in a modal (just incase you didn't). I have it so I press the save button and it segues back to the TabBarController. I did have it set up to go to the VC originally but the TabBar was not appearing. I did just set up a cancel button that does the same thing (but doesn't save the content).

Comment: You can also select to "view raw image which even larger.

Comment: I think you could try setting up a segue to that 3rd VC instead of to the Tab Bar Controller. Let me do some experiments and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Yea I tried that with all the possible options. Only thing left is doing a custom one I think. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you should never go back to a previous controller with a segue, unless you use an unwind segue -- you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance of the tab bar controller. What kind of segue are you using to go from the table view to the controller on the far right? Which controller do you want to go back to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class for the VC that is not in the TabBar, create an IBAction from the "Back" button and just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Here is a link to the sample project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B174p0JH6p7uQ1pLQnhuOEV0ejA/edit?usp=sharing

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I tried this. The problem is that when you transition back to vc2 from vc3 there is no tab bar at the bottom of the screen which is why I was going back to the TabBarController (so that the tab bar would show).

Comment: Oops. My bad. I overlooked that.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new link. I think I've solved it.

Comment: @Shan, do you know how to dismissViewCOntroller and set it so that it goes back to VC1? My full question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061740/segue-back-from-modal-to-first-tab-bar/32061847?noredirect=1#comment52101925_32061847